# Preserving Folder Structure While Applying S3 Deletion Rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, s3-lifecycle-policy

I have my S3 Bucket where I want apply the rule for a folder inside C3/TempData/Tasks I want that the entire data inside my Tasks fodler should get deleted. the rule worked accordingly, but it also delted the Tasks folder, how can I apply the rule so my Tasks folder should not get delete. Please guide me with the correct steps/resolution.

Comment: There are no folders. Why do you care if Tasks is gone as well? If there is no file with Tasks/ as part of the key then there is no Tasks folder anymore.

Answer (score -1):

- It sounds like you're using Amazon S3 Lifecycle rules to
  automatically delete objects in the "Tasks" folder inside your S3
  bucket.
- However, you want to ensure that the "Tasks" folder itself is not
  deleted.
- The behavior you're experiencing is expected because S3    doesn't
  actually have folders; it uses a flat namespace with keys    that
  include the full path.
- When you delete all objects with a    certain prefix (such as
  "C3/TempData/Tasks/"), it effectively removes    the "folder" as
  well.

I think this might have answered your question.

Comment: Yes, Correct but is there any way to resolve this issue ?